# Is it possible to create a PostGIS sequence to populate Area column of a polygon

Tags: qgis, postgis

I've created Postgres/PostGIS sequences before to assign unique gid values when a feature is created in QGIS but is it possible to create a sequence that will automatically populate an area column? Equally would it be possible for a sequence to be created to calculate the length of a line and even better the X Y values of a point?

Comment: I believe it's not a sequence you are looking for. Sequence, create consequent numbers, what you want is to calculate values from your geometries, right? And If I understood well, you want to do it automaticly. I think for that you need to set triggers.

Comment: I see, this is probably why I couldn't find anything on sequences and areas when doing a google search!

Comment: IF I'm reading the stuff on triggers correctly, then in theory I can create triggers to auto update fields for when a feature is created or edited?

Comment: exactly! See micha's example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a sample I use to update both lon/lat columns and x-y columns each time a point is added

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_lonlat_coords()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE g integer;
BEGIN
    g:=NEW.gauge_id;
    UPDATE rain_gauges 
        SET x_coord=ST_X(the_geom), y_coord=ST_Y(the_geom)    
        WHERE gauge_id=g;
    UPDATE rain_gauges 
        SET lon=ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(the_geom,4326)), lat=ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(the_geom,4326))    
        WHERE gauge_id=g;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Answer (score 3):

A sequence isn't what you want here.  You are looking for Triggers and [Rules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/rules-update.html)

Example coming

Answer (score 1):

triggers can do that for you. Search for example, you have a plsql function that uses x y data to fill geometry column. 
Régis